# How to handle after_create error? (trying to create webhook)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-api, trello

I am new at backend developing. Sorry for my English.

Now I am working at RoR app using Trello Api.

I have Relation model in my app.
I need to create webhooks after Relation object was created. But also I need to create Relation object if Webhook cannot be created (because it already exists). 
NOTE: I am using ruby-trello gem. Trello::Webhook class from ruby-trello gem.

app/models/relation.rb:

```
  after_create :create_webhook

  def create_webhook
    if self.kind == 'Board'
      Trello::Webhook.create({description: "Webhook for #{self.child_id}", callback_url: "#{CALLBACK_URL}/webhooks", id_model: self.child_id})
    end
  end
```

If Webhook already exists, I have error, example from server log:

```
E, [2019-05-23T14:57:37.127939 #18797] ERROR -- : [400 POST https://api.trello.com/1/webhooks]: A webhook with that callback, model, and token already exists
```

Example from rails console:

```
irb(main):008:0> Trello::Webhook.create({description: '', callback_url: '*hid_specially_for_security*', id_model: '*id_model_hid_specially*'})
E, [2019-05-23T15:21:26.416253 #22661] ERROR -- : [400 POST https://api.trello.com/1/webhooks]: A webhook with that callback, model, and token already exists
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):8
Trello::Error (A webhook with that callback, model, and token already exists)
```

How can I handle Trello::Error for creating Relation object despite that Webhook already exists?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: instead of create use this https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_initialize_by

Comment: Try [`find_or_create_by`](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by)

Comment: @Vishal there is no 'find_or_initialize_by' or 'find_or_create_by' merhod for Trello::Webhook:class. I am using ruby-trello gem. This class from gem.

Comment: can you put it in a `begin` `rescue` block ?

Comment: @AnatoliiStupin its rails method. first find record if it exists don't do anything , if its not exist create record